# How can I put the result of a derived function into a DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```js
import pandas as pd

def fib(num):
   if num <= 2:
       return 1
   else:
       return(fib(num-1) + fib(num-2))




def lo():
 A1 = int(input("number of days you want? = "))


 if A1 <= 0:    
    print("NO!404")
 else:
     print("daily rabbit population")   
     for i in range(A1): 
         print(fib(i))
        
lo()        



data = {'Product': [lo()]}

        

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Product', 'Price'])

print (df)
```

I let it work, but the results of it.

number of days you want? = 12
daily rabbit population
1
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
number of days you want? = 12
daily rabbit population
1
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
Product Price
0    None   NaN

> 

Comment: How do you stop your loop?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: ลูปของฉันจะถูกให้สิ้นสุดตามจำนวนที่กำหนด ใน
 A1 = int(input("number of days you want? = "))


Corralien

Comment: The expected result is that I want the result of the Fibonacci Sequence number into the DataFrame.

Comment: Can you check my answer below if it's what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `lo` function as follow:

```
def lo():
    A1 = int(input("number of days you want? = "))

    if A1 <= 0:    
        print("NO!404")
    else:
        print("daily rabbit population")   
        return [fib(i) for i in range(A1)]

data = {'Product': lo()}  # remove []
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Product', 'Price'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    Product Price
0         1   NaN
1         1   NaN
2         1   NaN
3         2   NaN
4         3   NaN
5         5   NaN
6         8   NaN
7        13   NaN
8        21   NaN
9        34   NaN
10       55   NaN
11       89   NaN
```